# Interrogative form of this sentence

Tags: interrogatives

> Ask for the **bold part**.
>
> They are running **home**.

I thought the answer must be "*Where are they running to?*" but when I checked the answer it was "*Where are they running?*". If the sentence is transformed as "Where are they running?" then it does not express the same sense as that of the original sentence because in this case the answer would be much like "They are running at home". So, what's the correct form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sense of in your question

> Where are they running **to**?

is the question for

> They are running **home**

that is, in a **homeward** direction

> Where are they running?

asks **at which location** are they running

> They are running **in the park**
>   They are running **along the road**

Comment: So the correct answer should be "Where are they running to?", right?

Comment: @Sarthak123 Yes, I would say the **to** should be there. Where did you **check the answer**? Is it a workbook?

Comment: nah I was doing some exercises on the internet, the answer written there seemed confusing. Thanks for your help !

Comment: As a native speaker, I disagree: I don't think anybody hearing "Where are they running?" would think it should mean "Where are they, right now, as they are in the act of running?"  Running is inherently an act of motion; if you are running, then you are presumably running to somewhere.  Consider "Where are they going?" or "Where are they living?" - you don't have to say "Where are they going to?" or "Where are they living at?"